# Running a WebDriver Test without using ANT, Maven, JUnit or Eclipse

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to know if it's possible to run a WebDriver test in Java using just a plain text editor, Firefox browser, Java SDK and WebDriver JAR?

I am trying to come up with the most "bare-metal" way to run a test without adding Test Runners, Test Frameworks, Dependency Managers into the mix.

I understand that this is not the "right" way to do things, but I am trying to find a way to create a new kind of WebDriver tutorial that will focus only on the API.

I am using OS X right now but instructions for Windows would be equally appreciated.

Comment: Of course it's possible. But question:  `"Why? What's the gain?"`

Comment: I'd say the gain is not having to install and master additional software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running WebDriver is as simple as

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

The only thing that you need is a correct classpath, which is just `selenium-java-2.38.0.jar` and supporting libraries, namely: `guava-15.0.jar` `json-20080701.jar` `commons-exec-1.1.jar` `httpcore-4.3.jar` `httpclient-4.3.1.jar` `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar`

Or, as per JimEvans, you can download standalone [selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar) that has all dependencies included.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to run the test using only selenium-standalone server. Where would I need the other JARs you have listed out i.e. guava-15.0.jar json-20080701.jar commons-exec-1.1.jar httpcore-4.3.jar httpclient-4.3.1.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

Comment: The standalone .jar file contains the other .jars zipped inside it, so if you're using the standalone .jar, you don't need the others. In point of fact, that's the purpose of the "standalone" .jar, that you don't need to track the dependency .jars. For those who like that kind of masochism, the API-only `selenium-java-<version>.jar` is provided.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly record and run the script you want to do then export it as junit4 test suite and save. Second copy the full code and aste it in eclipse then you can get the option "Run as junit4 test" while running code.