# Downloading webpages and their resources within Java

Tags: java, html, url, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to download all comments for a given news article (in www.theguardian.com) I can get the article in Java and parse with Jsoup to obtain the url for the comments but when I try to download I get only a default page and number of comments (50). For instance the url for the comments might be
http://discussion.theguardian.com/discussion/p/2nzaq

If I load this page in Firefox and login with my user id I get the option to display all comments and the url becomes 
.../p/2nzaq#show-all

but still java when given this url downloads only the default 50 comments same with .../p/2nzaq?orderby=newest&per_page=50&commentpage=1

Now I thought of trying wget or aria2 at the command prompt (windows) or through executing a shell command within java to obtain the comments with any of these urls and still the same default comment page and number. Firefox seems to have no problem displaying and downloading all comments. How can I automate this in java? Thanks

per comment below

Tried HttpClient with

```
public class DownloadFile {

public static void getFile(String url, String filepath) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();        
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        //long len = entity.getContentLength();
        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(entity.getContent());
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filepath)));
        int inByte;
        while((inByte = bis.read()) != -1) bos.write(inByte);
        bis.close();
        bos.close();
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Integer ii = 3;
        String MyUrl = "http://discussion.theguardian.com/discussion/p/2nzaq?orderby=newest&per_page=50&commentpage=" + ii.toString();
        String MyFilePath = "./testfile" + ii.toString() + ".htm";
        getFile(MyUrl,MyFilePath);  
}
```

}

Also tried similar with ".../p/2nzaq#show-all" I did discover that the HttpClient tutorial is wrong and you can't instantiate HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(); this yields HttpClient is abstract; cannot be instantiated ---I found in another post here that HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); is ok

Comment: Have you tried with `HttpClient`?

Comment: Everything after the # is ignored except by client-side Javascript.

Comment: Tried HttpClient with the following code but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need a browser to do that. You can control the browser from Java using Selenium. Setting it up is really straightforward and takes minutes, please refer to my answer here: [Running a WebDriver Test without using ANT, Maven, JUnit or Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600531/running-a-webdriver-test-without-using-ant-maven-junit-or-eclipse/22600641#22600641).

After you open that URL in Selenium you get all the comments from current page, then programmatically click next button and loop until you reach the final page.